# How to use sed command with regular expression?

Tags: bash, sed

I have an input file (PowerCenter xml file) and I need to replace a shortcut for a target environment. So I need to find a line with `SHORTCUT` and then change a parameter in `REPOSITORYNAME`

I am trying to find the substring from `REPOSITORYNAME` to eol and replace the first occurrence of "whatever" between quotes. I have found a regex ".*?" which works in regexr.com, but not in bash

```
input=SHORTCUT COMMENTS="" REFERENCETYPE="LOCAL" REFOBJECTNAME="mplt_EBXSOAPExport" REPOSITORYNAME="ZRH_PCE_P01" VERSIONNUMBER="1"/>"

x=$(echo $input | grep -o 'REPOSITORYNAME.*>' | sed -r '{0,/\".\+?\"/s/\".\+?\"/\"TARGET\"/}')
echo $x;


input="SHORTCUT COMMENTS="" REFERENCETYPE="LOCAL" REFOBJECTNAME="mplt_EBXSOAPExport" REPOSITORYNAME="any_word" VERSIONNUMBER="1"/>"

another possible input="SHORTCUT COMMENTS="" REFERENCETYPE="LOCAL" REFOBJECTNAME="mplt_EBXSOAPExport" REPOSITORYNAME = "any_word" VERSIONNUMBER="1"/>"

output="SHORTCUT COMMENTS="" REFERENCETYPE="LOCAL" REFOBJECTNAME="mplt_EBXSOAPExport" REPOSITORYNAME="updated" VERSIONNUMBER="1"/>"
```

Thanks

Comment: [regexr.com](https://regexr.com) uses JavaScript & php/pcre regex syntax; `sed -r` uses "Extended" regex syntax ("ERE"), which is a fair bit different. For one thing, ERE doesn't have the "`*?`" operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
sed '/SHORTCUT/s/REPOSITORYNAME\s*=\s*"[^"]*"/REPOSITORYNAME="WhatYouWant"/'
```

It tests that a line contains SHORTCUT and when it does it performs a search/replace matching the REPOSITORYNAME and its value and replacing the latter by a new one.

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/1rr3nd) !

Comment: hi Aaron, yes it works with the given input... what if there were spaces? it is also possible

Comment: @karoles I hadn't seen your second sample input, I've changed my command to accept spaces around the equal sign and have added a link to a test run that tests both your samples